# Automated scheduled hard drive partition copying

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, backup, scheduled-tasks

How can I automate a scheduled (e.g. once a week) backup of a hard drive *partition*? Copying partitions is always much faster than interpreting a file system. I'd settle for something that targets the first directory to a second.

Comment: And the OS is…? "Copying partitions is always much faster than interpreting a file system" – not always (e.g. 100 GiB partition vs 1MiB of data inside the filesystem). What is your research so far?

Comment: Just about every disk-level backup software can do this (e.g. Acronis, Macrium, etc.). Are you looking for software (in which case you should narrow down your requirements and ask on [softwarerecs.se] instead) or an ad-hoc `dd`-esque script?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my search, we can try to do scheduled automatic Windows backup by the tool——AOMEI  Backupper. It is supported to do file backup, folder backup, system backup, partition backup and disk backup.

How to use the tool, we can refer the link.
https://www.backup-utility.com/windows-10/schedule-automatic-backup-windows-10-1128.html

In addition, I also search a way to backup our hard drive automatically by script.
The following article says "This tutorial is demonstrated using Windows XP, however it will extend equally well into Windows Vista", so  I am not sure if it can be used in the other version of windows, but I think we can have a try.

For details, please refer the article.
[Four ways to automatically backup your hard drive](https://www.lifehack.org/articles/featured/four-ways-to-automatically-backup-your-hard-drive.html)